# How to perform click actions for ExpandableListview Group and Child items in Android Espresso?

Tags: android, click, expandablelistview, android-espresso

[image]I have tried with Espresso record and other click actions but those didn't perform clicks on ExpandableListview group and child, Can anyone help regarding this ?

Comment: It's not clear what you've tried so far. What kind of errors are you getting? What code have you tried specifically?

Comment: @M onView(withText("Generals")).perform(click()); &



onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.exp_listview))
                .atPosition(1).onChildView(withId(R.id.list_item)).
                perform(click()); &



onView(withId(R.id.list_item)).perform(click());

Comment: What happens? What the error messages?

Comment: android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Generals"

Comment: have you tried using (hasDescendant(withText("Generals")))?

Comment: It returns android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'has descendant: with text: is "Counter / Statements"' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137029/discussion-between-peddiraju-and-michael-vescovo).

Comment: Did you arrive at any valid Answer for this question?

Comment: ****Matches**** is when there are multiple views that match the said criteria and espresso is not able to decide which one.